# nonetype object has no attribute 'text' only from linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm using phyton 3.6.9 from debian and I'm having a problem with my code.

*What does my code do?*
My code extracts news from an xml url (using bs4 and urllib) and publishes it on a telegram channel using the telepot library. The check takes place on the date of publication.

*What is my problem?*
My code works perfectly from windows. From Linux it performs the scraping correctly, but when I arrived at the last news on the site, it returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 32, in <module>
    get_data()
  File "bot.py", line 27, in get_data
    prev_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(news_list[0].pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**I've already tried some solutions featured here on Stackoverflow!**

*This is my code:*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import time
import datetime
import telepot

BOT_TOKEN = " ... "
bot = telepot.Bot(BOT_TOKEN)

def get_data():
    global prev_date_time
    site = 'http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/rss102.xml'
    op = urlopen(site)
    rd = op.read()
    op.close()
    sp_page = soup(rd, 'html.parser')
    news_list = sp_page.find_all('item')
    for news in news_list:

        if prev_date_time and prev_date_time >= datetime.datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'):
            break
        print(news.title.text)
        bot.sendMessage('-1001335964270', news.title.text)

    if news_list:
        prev_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(news_list[0].pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
prev_date_time = None

while True:
    get_data()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the element is `pubdate` not `pubDate` and python is case-sensitive, so you need to use exact name:

```
prev_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(news_list[0].pubdate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```